# Should these two tidal forces questions be asked in Astronomy SE instead of here?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Two questions just asked:

1. [How do we know that an exoplanet is tidally locked to the parent star?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/33976/12102)
2. [Do tides occur on planets like Neptune, having water?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/33971/12102)

while probably not off-topic here, are definitely on-topic in Astronomy SE, and might receive better answers there. The first even has aspects of observational astronomy of exoplanets and solar system evolution which may not really be on-topic here.

Further, they both involve tidal forces, which happens to be [this month's featured tag in Astronomy](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/480/7982)!

While answering them here with short, basic answers might be helpful to the OPs, I think both of these could receive better answers in Astronomy and those answers would serve readers there better.

I wonder if these should be both migrated there?

**update:** The've booth been migrated

---

**Question:** I wonder if it's possible to start sketching out some basic helpful guidelines for what is better asked in Astronomy SE versus Space SE?

For example, question #1 involves both observational astronomy of exoplanets and solar system evolution over billions of years, and those really seem better asked in Astronomy.

I'm not suggesting we need a rule, but a few guidelines that can be pointed to in comments might be all it takes to raise awareness of a good way to tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Two questions just asked:
>
> 1. [How do we know that an exoplanet is tidally locked to the parent star?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/33976/12102)
> 2. [Do tides occur on planets like Neptune, having water?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/33971/12102)
>
> while probably not off-topic here, are definitely on-topic in Astronomy SE, and might receive better answers there. The first even has aspects of observational astronomy of exoplanets and solar system evolution which may not really be on-topic here.

Yes on all counts; it seems that that in these cases Astronomy is better for the reasons mentioned in the question.

As it turns out, they were migrated, well received, and received multiple well-received answers each, and each has an accepted answer.